# Filtering list returned by NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces

Tags: c#, .net

The NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces method returns a list of all interfaces on the system, but it returns a lot of seemingly garbage interfaces too like

xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%12

::1

in addition to "normal" ones like

127.0.0.1

192.168.0.3

etc

I only want keep these "normal" ones. What criteria (properties, methods) should I use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'garbage' ones are [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) addresses.  They're goodness.  But if you only need the IPv4 ones, do:

```
var list = NetworkInterface
    .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    .Where(n => n.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.First().Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using the LINW [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) method.

Something like

```
var yourList = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(x => /*your boolean expression here>*/)
```

Comment: I know how to programatically filter, I am asking which filtering criteria to use!